# Error in simple SQL command and the ways to resolve it

Tags: sql, oracle

The goal is to choose the city with the shortest name.

I am very new to SQL and I cannot understand the reason of the issue for the following query:

```
SELECT city, min(len)
  FROM ( SELECT city, length(city) AS len
           FROM station
           GROUP BY city
       )
;
```

It throws the error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

I googled the problem and it says that I must have `GROUP BY` if I use aggregation functions such as `min`. So I tried the following:

```
SELECT city, min(len)
  FROM ( select city, length(city) AS len
           FROM station
           GROUP BY city
       )
  GROUP BY city
;
```

But that gives me min for every city (as I suspect).

Then I tried to `group by len`:

```
SELECT city, min(len)
  FROM ( select city, length(city) AS len
           FROM station
           GROUP BY city
       )
  GROUP BY len
;
```

but it gives me another error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I do not understand why...
How would I choose min in the entire column?

[image]

Comment: This is not MySQL and not SQL Server

Comment: You have tagged the question with both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server yet get an Oracle error message.  Do you know what DBMS you are using?

Comment: @DanGuzman haha... no! I just picked this SQL track on HackerRank.. I did not know what DBMS it uses. But thanks for clarifying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more than one city with the same minimum length. If you first find what that minimum length is, then you can filter based on that length:

```
SELECT city
  FROM station
  WHERE length(city) = (SELECT MIN(length(city)) FROM station)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more approaches specifically for Oracle:

If more than one city ties for the shortest name, list them all (requires Oracle 12.1):

```
select city, length(city)
from   station
order by length(city)
fetch first row with ties;
```

Report only one city with the shortest name, using alphabetical order as a tie-breaker:

```
select city, length(city)
from   station
order by length(city), city
fetch first row only;
```

For earlier versions of Oracle:

```
select city, name_length
from   ( select city, length(city) as name_length
              , dense_rank() over (order by length(city)) as length_rank
         from   station )
where  length_rank = 1
order by city;
```